# MySQL - adding where clause in PivotTable results

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, case-when

I have this code which creates a pivot table

```
BEGIN
DECLARE currentDate varchar(45);
SET currentDate = CURDATE();
SET @sql = NULL;
SET group_concat_max_len=1500000;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'CASE WHEN c.mmFeedcode = ''',
      mmFeedcode,
      ''' THEN c.ratio else '''' END AS `',
     replace(mmFeedcode,'.','/'), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM eqderiv.HedgeRatio
inner join eqderiv.EtfInventory
on mmFeedcode = ETF 
where date= currentDate and isDecomposed=1 and eqderiv.EtfInventory.etfInventory in ('FW','FH') ;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT replace(replace(replace(replace(c.hedgeFeedcode,''.PF.'',''/PF/''),''.UN'',''-U''),''.'',''/''),''/PR/'',''.PR.''), ', @sql, ' 
            from eqderiv.HedgeRatio c
              inner join eqderiv.EtfInventory i
                on c.mmFeedcode = i.ETF
              where c.date=  ''' ,currentDate,'''  and c.isDecomposed=1 and i.etfInventory in (''FW'',''FH'') and i.hedgeInventory in (''FW'',''FH'')
            group by c.hedgeFeedcode');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

In my pivot results I need to add a condition where i would use isDecomposed =1 if mmFeedCode has no lines where hedgeFeedCode = mmFeedcode and is not in etfHedgeInventory = ('FW', 'FH')

Sample Data

table c

```
mmFeedCode  hedgeFeedCode
ABC xyz
ABC gfh
ABC fds
ABC uty
XYZ OOO
XYZ PPP
XYZ QQQ
XYZ RRR
```

table i

```
etf etfInventory    etfHedgeInventory
XYZ FW  GM
```

in that case the output should be

```
    ABC
xyz ratio
gfh ratio
fds ratio
uty ratio
```

and not

```
    ABC
gfh ratio
fds ratio
uty ratio
OOO ratio
PPP ratio
QQQ ratio
RRR ratio
```

Comment: So what's the question or the problem?

Comment: As of now in all cases i get the "Not desired" output i need to check if mmFeedCode as a hedgeFeedCode = mmFeedCode that etfHedgeInventory is not in FW or FH